# Compare and Match Array Values

Tags: ios, regex, swift, parse-platform

When the user searches for a category I need all the arrays that contain that same category to appear + the other categories that are in that respective array.

Once the user has chosen `["Apples", "Oranges", "Limes"]` I want to compare which array (out of many) that I queried contains Apples, Oranges or Limes. This can be **one** array or this can be **many** arrays.

These are the arrays I'm adding the values to:

```
 var categoryNeeded = [AnyObject]()  //The user creates this one and adds values to it

 var categoryArr = [AnyObject]() //The Parse arrays are added here:
```

I have a simple Parse query function.

```
var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
query.whereKey("contacts", containsString: "\(categoryArr)")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in               
    if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
        for object in objects {            
            self.categoryArr.append(object["contacts"] as! AnyObject)
            print(self.categoryArr)
        }
    }
}
```

The 2nd line is suspect:

```
query.whereKey("contacts", containsString:  "\(categoryArr)")
```

When querying with that line, I get this error (without a crash):

> 2016-01-23 15:53:47.508 CC[28514:5733236] [Error]: $regex only works
>   on string fields (Code: 102, Version: 1.11.0)

Without the `whereKey` line, I get all the values and it prints them. I just can't figure out how to compare and check for matches between the two arrays which ultimately gives the matching arrays. Is there a Swift method that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `containsString` but rather `containedIn`:

```
query.whereKey("contacts", containedIn: categoryArr)
```

Comment: Just an addition to this already simple answer, if you're wanting realtime (or as near as) when it comes to speed, then it'd be best to consult the Accelerate framework (but this is pretty much only for high-capacity work such as mathematical waveforms)